# Python - Find max and min from text file with integer and string

Tags: python, max, min

I've been trying to get the maximum/minimum value from a text file, but I don't know how to only take the integer of the text, python always take the string in the text and give me an error.
Here's an exemple of the text file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Xcdq.png)
Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You can find `int` values of your text using `pandas.DataFrame.dtypes`. Here is your data and I assume that you saved it as a `test.txt` file:

```
E1    10    14    15
E2    10    13    10
E3    20    17    18
E4    13    10    11
E5    12    20    12
E6    14    16    14
E7    13    12    08
E8    14    16    15
```

You can read the data using `Pandas` and then find the columns that contain `int` values. Then you can search for the maximum integer value:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.txt" , delimiter="\s+" , header= None)

maximum = 0
for col in df.columns:
    if df.dtypes[col] == "int64":
        if max(df[col])>maximum:
            maximum = max(df[col])
```

Then if you try to `print(maximum)`, you'll get this:

```
20
```

So **the critical part is to check the type of members of each column of the DataFrame!** If you try to `print(df.dtypes)`, you'll get this:

```
0    object
1     int64
2     int64
3     int64
dtype: object
```

This means, the first column(which contained E1, E2, ..., E8) has an `object` type, and the other ones have an `int64` type(which you're looking for).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Pandas unless needed. There's a much cleaner, simpler solution:

```py
# Open the file
with open("filename.txt") as file:  # edit file name here
    text = file.readlines()  # a list of strings, each representing a line


# Get the values
values_2d = [[int(j) for j in i.split()[1:]] for i in text]  # turn them into integers (ignoring the first column), but it's still two-dimensional
values = sum(values_2d, []) # turn into a 1-dimensional list
print(f"Maximum: {max(values)}, minimum: {min(values)}")  # output
```

It's somewhat inefficient in the `sum(,[])` part, but that's only been used for brevity.

Comment: Please note one should always use context managers when dealing with files in Python

Comment: I modified the program to use a context manager.

Comment: There is no reason to save the lines to a list. Just do `for i in file`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't tagged or mentioned any libraries so I'm going to assume you want a solution in vanilla Python. Your file format is a bit unambiguous, which smallest integer do you want to find? If you want to get the smallest integer in each row separately, you can open the file, read the lines into a list and extract the integers out of it:

```py
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    # Find the first spacebar in the line, then slice
    # it from there to the end, and remove trailing newline
    temp = line[line.index(' '):].strip()

    # Loop through each number, but since there are multiple
    # spaces between numbers, skip empty strings
    # This can be done more easier with regular expressions
    numbers = temp.split(' ')
    # Look up the filter function on Python docs to learn what it does
    numbers = filter(lambda x: (not not x) or x == '0', map(int, numbers))
    print(min(numbers), max(numbers))
```

Comment: `temp` is not necessary. `split` already removes newline with the default separator and you can just slice the result. Just `numbers = line.split()[1:]`. Also what's the point of that `filter`? It is not asked for

Comment: Isn't `lambda x: not not x` just `bool`?

Comment: @Tomerikoo Filter is there to, well, filter the empty strings. Judging by the file OP attached, there might be multiple spaces between number. `.split()`ting that string would result in a list of multiple empty strings. Feel free to try it yourself.

@Mous It is a bool, rather it is returing True for Truey values (which is, thanks for reminding, not a good idea if a number happens to be 0)

Comment: I meant, isn't `bool(x)` always equal to `(lambda x:not not x)` for all x? The lambda is very marginally faster.

Comment: `split` with the default argument removes ***all*** whitespaces so no, you will not have empty strings... Try it yourself `"hello       world".split()` gives `["hello", "world"]`